# How to display Google Glass screen on my PC

Tags: android, remote-desktop, google-glass

What tool should I use to display Google Glass screen on my desktop computer?
It is needed for demo purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can connect to your Glass with `adb` and then use some of the tools that mirror Android device screen.

[Here is a tutorial](http://neatocode.tumblr.com/post/49566072064/mirroring-google-glass) explaining how you can do this in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I recently developed screencast clone running on PC. It does not require `adb`, only need bluetooth connection.

Check it out here: https://github.com/thorikawa/GlassRemote

Answer (score 0):

configure Droid@Screen with adb and connect glass using USB. then you get glass screen on your pc screen